# VBA (Macros) executed from JAVA program

Tags: java, excel, vba, auto-generate

I am try to generate an excel report base on output from a JAVA program each time the program is executed. So from the way i see it, there are several steps to achieve this.
(I have done some research but may have some holes in my understanding, please correct me if I'm wrong)

---

1) Inserted output into an excel workbook (which i understand can be done using Apache poi but only to read/write).

2 (option A) ) Have pre-written VBA code in each workbook. Have JAVA program execute said macros which will generate my desired report format.

2 (option B) ) With the new excel Workbook created in step 1, have JAVA execute an external code on the workbook (VBS?) which does the same function as option A

Will either of these method work? I keep seeing terms such as JAVA-COM bridge. But i don't understand what it does. What are libraries/methods I can use to achieve this

Thanks for your help everyone

Comment: [link1](http://sachinmalkar.blogspot.com/2010/02/run-excel-macro-from-java.html) , [link2](http://javaprogramming.language-tutorial.com/2012/10/run-excel-macro-from-java.html) and [link3](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-execute-macro-using-java) may help.